# How to truncate decimal number digits in thymleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I wanted to show only full number and not anything after decimal. How i can achieve that in thymleaf? For example it is showing 120.0 and i want to show  120 that's it.

Comment: convert it to int :)

Comment: Please show an example of your code.

Comment: @leviand how to convert to int in thymleaf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Numbers`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/expression/Numbers.html) utility and set the `decimalDigits` to 0:

```
${#numbers.formatDecimal(value, 0, 0)}
```

> public String formatDecimal(Number target,
>                               Integer minIntegerDigits,
>                               Integer decimalDigits)